# How to call jquery ajax form plugin's function showResponse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i am facing problem in showing ajax call " request response" in alert method.

i checked the ajax call in browser it shows response well, mean ajax call works and it gets some repose but this reponse does not alert in showRepose method

here is my code

jQuery( window ).ready(function() 
    {

```
    var atts = <?php echo json_encode($atts ); ?>;
    var options = { 
        target:'#output2',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 


        // other available options: 
         url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",        // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        //url:"<?php echo PLUGIN_URI; ?>check-ajax.php",
        data:{'btn_send_form_email':'1','process_ajax':'1','atts':JSON.stringify(atts),'action':'get_post_information'},
        type:"post",        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:showResponse , // post-submit callback 

     }; 

    // bind to the form's submit event 

    jQuery("form[name='wemblo_frontend_form_<?php echo $form_id;?>").submit(function() 
    { 
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }); 


    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  
    { 
        // for normal html responses, the first argument to the success callback 
        // is the XMLHttpRequest object's responseText property 

        // if the ajaxSubmit method was passed an Options Object with the dataType 
        // property set to 'xml' then the first argument to the success callback 
        // is the XMLHttpRequest object's responseXML property 

        // if the ajaxSubmit method was passed an Options Object with the dataType 
        // property set to 'json' then the first argument to the success callback 
        // is the json data object returned by the server 

        alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
            '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the `target` attribute in option but did not mark the div in HTML with `id="output2"`. After I did that it worked. Thanks!